# Search form as list item in menu?

Tags: menus, search, list

What is the best way to do this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=>'Primary', 
                         'container'=>'',
                         'items_wrap'=>'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<li>'.get_search_form().'</li></ul>') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any item you want to a menu by filtering `wp_nav_menu_items`.
From the tutorial [How to Add a Search to Menu](http://bavotasan.com/2011/adding-a-search-bar-to-the-nav-menu-in-wordpress/), this is how you'd add a search form:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {

        $searchform = get_search_form( false );

        $items .= '<li>' . $searchform . '</li>';

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: `get_search_form()` can return instead of echo by passing false. [See codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)